# How to call a function with parameter onload or after dom is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, selecteditem, selectedvalue

I have the following function that takes a selected value and runs it onclick. I will still leave it that way. However, client wants to have a default selected value which should run the function and this function makes changes on the page.

So how should I run this function by taking pre-selected value and run it after dom is ready without clicking anything?

```
var value = $("#market-select option:selected").text(); // this takes value of pre-selected item
vizFilter1(value); // and I want to call this function after dom is ready or onload after passing values.
```

I tried it this way but it is not doing anything.

```
$(document).ready(function (){

function run (){
var value = $("#market-select option:selected").text();
vizFilter1(value);

}

});
```

How to run this after page has been loaded without requiring the user to do anything?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to run those two lines of code from multiple places, e.g., from a click handler and on DOM ready, wrap them in a function (as you've done) and then *call that function* from your DOM ready handler. Or simply bind the function as the ready handler:

```
function run (){
  var value = $("#market-select option:selected").text();
  vizFilter1(value);
}

$(document).ready(function (){
  run();
  // do other on ready things here if required
});

// OR, if you don't need to do other things:
$(document).ready(run);
```

In the attempt you showed, you declared a `run()` function but never called it. Though it is fine to define the function inside your ready handler as long as you then call it - that may be preferable as it keeps the function out of global scope.

Comment: it is still not working. I can call vizFilter1 in the console with no issue but document ready is no longer working! why do you think is that?

Comment: I don't know. Given you mentioned the console I assumed you've checked that no error messages are logged?

Comment: nope. it is not working!  <script type="text/javascript"> 

function run(){
var value = $("#market-select option:selected").text();


VizGlobal(value);

}


$(document).ready(function(){    
run();
alert(value)

$(document).ready(run);
});
  
  </script>

Comment: Are you saying the alert doesn't display? And no errors in the console? Note that in my answer I showed two different ways to use the document ready handler - you want one or the other, not both.

Comment: it seems like whatever that I have within vizFilter function is causing the issue as it loads after everything has been loaded. Not sure if that explains anything.  if I call vizFilter within document ready, vizFilter parameter is no longer working.